# Raycasting an instantly moved collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to move some transforms with attached colliders to a specific position, then check if one of them is hit by raycast.

I've done that the naive way (pseudo code) :

```
foreach(object in objects){
   actual_position = object.transform.position
   object.transform.position = object.new_position
}
if(Physics.Raycast(...)) objectHit();
// Then I revert each of them them back to their actual_position
```

After testing multiple times with the same context (same positions between tests for each objects), the raycast sometimes miss, sometimes not (~50/50).

Done a bit of research and found that in the Raycast doc page :

> If you move colliders from scripting or by animation, there needs to
>   be at least one FixedUpdate executed so that the physics library can
>   update its data structures, before a Raycast will hit the collider at
>   it's new position.

So I calmed my anger and started looking for a solution.
This thread has a way using a coroutine to wait the next tick :
[Raycast doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874377/raycast-doesnt-work-properly/30889118#30889118)

I'm affraid it won't work for me, as I need the objects to get back to their real position instantly.
This process can happen multiple times per frame (each time a player fire his weapon)

Is there a way to force the colliders update ?

If not... should I make my own raycasts and colliders ? :(

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using something like `Bounds.IntersectRay` ? If your object has a simple colliders on it, (or your raycasts dont need to be 100% accurate) for something as simple as a box collider, you could do `object.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds` to get the bounds, and move the bounds object to the new location, check it, and THEN only move the object if it did not collide, this would also  be better on performance than moving twice, as it would not even move it at all if it shouldnt, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.IntersectRay.html

Comment: Look like a smart solution, my colliders are simple capsules for the moment, but I guess this would work also for a more complex MeshCollider. The only problem I see is that I'll have to hit test every objects and make sure there is no wall between them and the ray origin. This is more complex than just throwing a raycast, but why not. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Looking at the answer you linked I was thinking that maybe you could try to use `yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();` since it will be called before each Physics update ?

Comment: @FLX You do not have to hit test every world object if thats what you mean, for each object you want to move you simply have to do a single `BoxCast` check (or `CapsuleCast` in your case), both of these put together are still many times more efficient than actually using colliders with rigidbodies (not to mention actually moving an object twice) - `CapsuleCast` are a little hard to grasp the first time, but very beneficial when you do understand them properly

Comment: @Kardux I don't think it can work in this case : I can have multiple rewinds at the same time, if I need to wait for the next tick I fear some positions could override another. I'm not so comfortable with routines so I might be wrong, but still the design would be over overcomplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround is to deactivate and activate Gameobject (attached collider) immediately. In this case collider position will be updated in single frame.
Another solution is
[Physics.autoSyncTransforms and Physics.SyncTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-autoSyncTransforms.html?_ga=2.186136297.159098127.1570644587-1317536171.1558971370)

Comment: Make sure to use Physics2D.SyncTransform() if you're making a 2D game.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this out (adding to your pseudo-code):

```
foreach(object in objects)
{
   actual_position = object.transform.position;
   object.transform.position = object.new_position;

   StartCoroutine(CheckToRevertOnNextFixedUpdate(object, actual_position));
}

IEnumerator CheckToRevertOnNextFixedUpdate(object, actual_position)
{
   yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

   if(Physics.Raycast(...)) objectHit();
   // Then I revert each of them them back to their actual_position
}
```

Essentially this delays your check to the next FixedUpdate() for each object - and reverts each of them if needed. I hope this is not overcomplicated, since you only add a few lines of code.

I'm also assuming that moving the object's position for 1 FixedUpdate() frame would not have a visual effect of the the object teleporting to the new position and back. However, you can always move the collider only, and then move the rest of the transform there after the FixedUpdate().

Comment: That's how they did in the linked thread, but if another player shoots while it's moved the actual_position could be wrong (am I right on this ?). Also Paradox's solution seems better in term of performance

Comment: @FLX The idea of using a coroutine is similar to that thread, but the details are somewhat different, applied to your context. If another player shoots while it's moved,it does not matter since the collider position is not yet updated in the next FixedUpdate() yet. And yes, Paradox's solution might be more efficient if you can approximate your collider shape to a bounding box and if the process of doing that does not incur significant overhead

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, the best method seems to be updating the `RigidBody.position`:

```
private Rigidbody Rigidbody;

void Start()
{
    Rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Upate()
{
    //.... your code
 
    Rigidbody.position = newPosition;
}
```

Much faster then deactivate/activate or `Physics.SyncTransform()`.